# No route matches [GET] "/password_resets/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, token

I'm following the [#275 Railscasts of Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test), but I can't make the tests pass, because of a problem with the `password_reset_token`.

Here is the test : **spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb**

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

subject { page }

describe "setting a new password" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }  
  before do
    visit new_password_reset_path
    fill_in t('user.email'), with: user.email
    click_button(t('submit.reset.password'))
    visit edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token)
  end

  it { should have_title(full_title(t('page.title.password_reset.edit'))) }
end
```

And here the error message :

```rb
 Failure/Error: before { visit edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token) }
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/password_resets/edit"
```

When I add a `puts user.password_reset_token` after `click_button(t('submit.reset.password'))`, I see the string is nil. But I don't understand why, can you help me out ?

Here is the **new_password_reset** view :

```rb
<%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email, t('user.email') %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag t('submit.reset.password'), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And the **edit_password_reset** view :

```rb
<% provide(:title, t('page.title.password_reset.edit')) %>
<%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, t('user.password') %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, t('user.password_confirmation') %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit t('submit.update.password'), class: "btn btn-primary"  %></div>
<% end %>
```

And the **new_password_reset** controller `create` and `edit` method :

```rb
def create 
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  flash[:success] = t('flash.success.reset_password.sent')
  redirect_to root_url
end 

def edit
  @user = User.find_by(password_reset_token: params[:id])
end
```

The `send_password_reset` is defined in the **user** model :

```rb
def send_password_reset
  self.password_reset_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!(validate: false)
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end
```

And there is the `rake routes` result :

```rb
password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)          password_resets#create
new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)      password_resets#new
edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format) password_resets#edit
password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)      password_resets#update
                PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)      password_resets#update
```

Comment: Would you post the output of `rake routes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `user.reload` after your `click_button` call.  The token has been written to the database, but the instance of `User` in your example is a different Ruby object than the instance in your model.